# Seperatiing vowels and consonents of Linked List in Java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list

> A linked list can be represented by the following structure:-
>
> ```
> struct Node
> {
> char data;
> struct Node* next;
> };
> struct Node
> {
> char data;
> struct Node* next;
> };class Node
> {
> public char data;
> public Node next;
> }class Node
> {
> public char data;
> public Node next;
> }
> ```
>
> You are given a function,
>
> ```
> struct Node* ReArrangeVowelsAndConsonants(struct Node* head);struct Node* 
>
> ReArrangeVowelsAndConsonants(struct Node* head);static Node 
>
> ReArrangeVowelsAndConsonants(Node head);static Node 
>
> ReArrangeVowelsAndConsonants(Node head);
> ```
>
> The pointer 'head' points to the start of a linked list. Implement the function to rearrange and return the same list so that all the vowels occupy the first half of the list and all the consonants occupy the second half.
>
> Note:
>
> 1. Do not create a new list, modify the existing list.
> 2. Relative ordering of vowels and consonants should not change among themselves.
> 3. You may assume that the list is of even length and half the nodes contain vowels and the other half contain consonants.
> 4. If the list is NULL, then return NULL.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>   a -> k -> r -> i -> t -> e -> o -> m
>
> Output:
>   a - >i - > e -> o -> k -> r -> t -> m
>
> Explanation:
>   The consonants k and r in the first half of the list are moved to the second half of the list, while vowels e and o in the second half of the list are moved to first half of the list, keeping the relative ordering same.

My Code performs the Operation correctly but does not satisfy the point 2 in note. The relative ordering of Elements changes in my output as I am swapping consonents with the Vowels. My Code is below....I just need how to make my code work for that case also.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Node
{
    public char data;
    public Node next;
    public static Node rearrange(Node head)
    {
        Node start=new Node();
        Node curr=new Node();
        Node temp=new Node();
        start=curr=head;
        int begin=0;
        int flag=0;
        while(head.next!=null)
        { 
            if(head.data=='a'||head.data=='e'||head.data=='i'||head.data=='o'||head.data=='u')
            {      // no change
            }
            else
            {
                curr=head.next;
                do
                {
                     System.out.println("CURR "+curr.data+" HEAD "+head.data);
                    if(curr.data=='a'||curr.data=='e'||curr.data=='i'||curr.data=='o'||curr.data=='u')
                    {
                     temp.data=curr.data;
                     curr.data=head.data;
                     head.data=temp.data;
                     break;
                    }
                }while((curr=curr.next)!=null);
            }
            head=head.next;
        }

        while(start.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(start.data+"->");
            start=start.next;
        }
        System.out.print(start.data);
        return start;

    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
      int count=0;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of characters:");
      int length=s.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the character seperated by ->");
      String inp=s.next();
      StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(inp,"->");
      Node[] a=new Node[inp.length()];
      for(int i=0;st.hasMoreElements();i++)
      {
        a[i]=new Node();
        a[i].data=(st.nextToken().toString()).charAt(0);
        count++;
      }
      a[count-1].next=null;
      for(int i=0;i<(count-1);i++)
      {
        a[i].next=a[i+1];
      }
      Node start =new Node();
      start=rearrange(a[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem definition is a bit incomplete: what happens when the first element is a consonant? If we are supposed to return the same head, then we need to do a content replacement. But if it's OK to return a different node as the head, we can have a solution based on re-linking.

Comment: Actually it appeared in a coding test. We only need to write the logic in the function and return the head. We can just change the head data with the other. I did it in my code as you can see in the "else" condition "Swapping". 
If the first element is a consonent and we have vowels in the further string we need to bring those vowels to the first. If we dint find any vowel the we can just return the head. 
Is it clarified or ??

Comment: Consider the input:

r->m->o->p->q->g->a

Expected Output:
o->a->r->m->p->q->g

My Program Output:
o->a->r->p->q->g->m

This creates the problem, the relative ordering changes as you can we need to get r->m->p->q->g
but i am getting  r->p->q->g->m

Comment: But I'm saying that if you are allowed to return a different node as the head, then re-linking rather than content swapping may be easier. The question is if this is allowed.

Comment: You are saying, if we can use :

temp=curr;
curr=head;
head=temp;
Right??
 @RealSkeptic

Comment: Well, not exactly. I mean inserting after a particular item by changing the `next` references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a reason why this exercise is using linked lists rather than an array. If you are allowed to return a new head, then rather than exchanging data between existing nodes, you can use a method that rearranges the nodes themselves. The advantage of this method is that you only need to traverse the list once.

The idea of this implementation is to keep a marker of the latest vowel we found. If we find another vowel, we take it out of the chain and put it after the existing latest vowel. E.g.:

```
a -> b -> c -> i -> x -> e
```

Say our `latestVowel` reference references the `a` node, and that we currently reached the `i` node. We do:

```
a -> i -> b -> c -> x -> e
```

So what was after the `a` is now after the `i`, and `a` links directly to `i`.

To properly remove and add links, it's best to use the item *before* the one you are checking. So if you have a `curr`, you will check `curr.next` to see if it's a vowel or not. If it is, it's easy to remove it from the chain by assigning its `next` to `curr`'s next. Of course you need to add it to its new place before you do that, or you might have a dangling chain.

Here is the method, with comments to explain each part:

```
public static Node rearrangeVowelsAndConsonants(Node head) {
    Node newHead = head;
    Node latestVowel;
    Node curr = head;

    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // We need to discover the first vowel in the list. It is going to be
    // the returned head, and also the initial latestVowel.
    if (isVowel(head.data)) {
        // Easy: first element is a vowel. It will also be the new head
        // and the initial latestVowel;
        latestVowel = head;
    } else {
        // First element is not a vowel. Iterate through the list until we
        // find a vowel. Note that curr points to the element *before*
        // the element with the vowel.
        while (curr.next != null && !isVowel(curr.next.data)) {
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        // This is an edge case where there are only consonants.
        if (curr.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        // Set the initial latestVowel and the new head to the vowel
        // item that we found. Relink the chain of consonants after
        // that vowel item:
        // old_head_consonant->consonant1->consonant2->vowel->rest_of_list becomes
        // vowel->old_head_consonant->consonant1->consonant2->rest_of_list
        latestVowel = newHead = curr.next;
        curr.next = curr.next.next;
        latestVowel.next = head;
    }

    // Now traverse the list. Curr is always the item *before* the one we are
    // checking, so that we can use it to re-link.
    while ( curr != null && curr.next != null ) {
        if (isVowel(curr.next.data)) {
            // The next discovered item is a vowel
            if (curr == latestVowel) {
                // If it comes directly after the previous vowel, we don't need
                // to move items around, just mark the new latestVowel and
                // advance curr.
                latestVowel = curr = curr.next;
            } else {
                // But if it comes after an intervening chain of consonants,
                // we need to chain the newly discovered vowel right after
                // the old vowel. Curr is not changed as after the re-linking
                // it will have a new next, that has not been checked yet,
                // and we always keep curr at one before the next to check.
                Node temp = latestVowel.next;   // Keep start of consonant chain
                latestVowel.next = curr.next;   // Chain in new vowel
                latestVowel = latestVowel.next; // Advance latestVowel
                curr.next = curr.next.next;     // Remove found vowel from previous place
                latestVowel.next = temp;        // Re-link the chain of consonants after lastestVowel.
            }
        } else {
            // No vowel in the next element, advance curr.
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
    return newHead;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement another sorting algorithm.
If you do not sort by swapping a vowel with a consonant but sort by going through and handing down the vowels by swapping them one by one with their previous element (if it is a consonant) you will sort the list and the relative ordering amongst vowels and consonants is untouched.

If you are unsure how to implement such a sorting algorithm, check out bubble sort:

[Bubble sort Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

Comment: Thats quite a good approach..!! But the Complexity of the algorithm will be more!! But Still to get the correct output this way of approach is good. I will implement it ! 
Thanks man ! I should have thought of sorting techiques! @Yindy

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here is the Correct Answer  after merging the previous answers. 
// It works Correctly...!
// Splitting Vowels And Consonants 

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Node 
{
    public char data;
    public Node next;
    public static Node rearrangeVowelsAndConsonants(Node head) {
        Node newHead = head;
        Node latestVowel;
        Node curr = head;

        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }


        if (isVowel(head.data)) {

            latestVowel = head;
        } else {

            while (curr.next != null && !isVowel(curr.next.data)) {
                curr = curr.next;
            }

            if (curr.next == null) {
                return head;
            }

            latestVowel = newHead = curr.next;
            curr.next = curr.next.next;
            latestVowel.next = head;
        }


        while ( curr != null && curr.next != null ) {
            if (isVowel(curr.next.data)) {

                if (curr == latestVowel) {

                    latestVowel = curr = curr.next;
                } else {

                    Node temp = latestVowel.next;   
                    latestVowel.next = curr.next;   
                    latestVowel = latestVowel.next; 
                    curr.next = curr.next.next;    
                    latestVowel.next = temp;        
                }
            } else {

                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }
        return newHead;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
          int count=0;
          System.out.println("Enter the character seperated by ->");
          String inp=s.next();
          StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(inp,"->");
          Node[] a=new Node[inp.length()];
          for(int i=0;st.hasMoreElements();i++)
          {
            a[i]=new Node();
            a[i].data=(st.nextToken().toString()).charAt(0);
            count++;
          }
          a[count-1].next=null;
          for(int i=0;i<(count-1);i++)
          {
            a[i].next=a[i+1];
          }
         Node start=rearrangeVowelsAndConsonants(a[0]);
        while(start.next!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(start.data+"->");
            start=start.next;
        }
        System.out.println(start.data);
        s.close();
    }
    public static boolean isVowel(char ch)
    {
        if(ch=='a'||ch=='e'||ch=='i'||ch=='o'||ch=='u')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }

}
```